# how to select the first N rows from a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

i am using postgresql. i want to be able to select or delete the first n rows after sorting the ascendingly according to the timestamp of insertion.
i found an example but it uses a table named logtable, i do not have that logtable.
in otherwords, i want to sort the records in the table based on the time of data insertion into the table then selected the first N rows

please let me know how to achieve this task

Comment: have you tried to replace logtable with your table name ?

Comment: @Sergey yes.....

Comment: Hi, it would help if you could add the table structure, a small data sample and the expected result. Preferably within a fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ts_insertion) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= N  -- replace N with your actual limit value
ORDER BY ts_insertion;
```

Comment: thnaks, but would it be sorted ascendingly in the way you provided?

Comment: Then add an `ORDER BY` clause to the outer query.

Comment: what about ts_insertion? i do not have it

Comment: please, i want to sort the entried according to the time of insertion ascendingly

Comment: Just replace `ts_insertation` with your column name.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the first n rows, you can use `LIMIT n`, a window function is not necessary.

You can also use `OFFSET`:

```
SELECT column1, column2
FROM table_name
ORDER BY column1 ASC
LIMIT row_count OFFSET row_to_skip;
```